# Why are my #links linking to my homepage

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm working on a page `http://www.example.com/control/policies/`

I made a link like this: `<a href="#">CLICK ME</a>`

When I click the link I arrive at `http://www.example.com/#` rather than `http://www.example.com/control/policies/#`

This happens for all `#` links (ie: `href="#payments"`, `href="#returns"`, etc.)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the fact that you set a `<base href="http://www.example.com/">` somewhere in the `<head>` of your HTML, which is affecting all relative links, including links to anchors.

Comment: I deleted my answer.  Not thought through!  Yours makes more sense.  +1

Comment: @Jason Thanks. I was a little worried there you actually believed what you were saying. ;)

Comment: You were exactly right! I was working on someone else's website and didn't realize they had it set. Thanks